# How can I escape ' character in powershell parameter?

Tags: regex, git, powershell, windows-scripting

What I have is a powershell script running in order to check differences in commits between two git branches.
Here's what I'm fetching from git expression:

```
$result  = Invoke-Expression "& git rev-list --left-right --count origin/$TargetBranch...origin/$SourceBranch 2>&1"
```

Unfortunately I have found out that when `$SourceBranch` contains `'`character it throws an

> [error]At line:1 char:143
>   + ..._move_to_record_icon_doesn't_respond 2>&1
>
> The string is missing the terminator: '.

I have implemented escaping of special characters like this:
`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape($SourceBranch)` then `` $SourceBranch.replace('\','`') ``

But it does not escape the `'` character, putting it into `` replace("'","`'") `` does not work either.

Powershell 5.0 used.

Comment: Try doubling the ampersand `$SourceBranch -replace "'", "''"`

Comment: See [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) for powershell

Comment: [Why Invoke-Expression is (harmful, evil, should be avoided)](https://www.bing.com/search?q=why+invoke-expression+is+harmful&form=ANNTH1&refig=5dc6d494d3eb4ad0b4c47df7b87935a7&sp=-1&pq=why+invoke-expression+is+harmfu&sc=0-31&qs=n&sk=&cvid=5dc6d494d3eb4ad0b4c47df7b87935a7)

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid `Invoke-Expression` altogether:

```
$result = & git rev-list --left-right --count origin/$TargetBranch...origin/$SourceBranch 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape a escape character itself.

An example to run `a'b.bat` in PowerShell,

```bsh
# create filename containing '
echo "echo 1" | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii "a'b.bat"

# double quote
Invoke-Expression ".\a``'b.bat"
Invoke-Expression ".\a''''b.bat"

# single quote
Invoke-Expression '.\a`''b.bat'
Invoke-Expression '.\a''''''''b.bat'

# with -replace operator
$source = ".\a'b.bat"
Invoke-Expression "cmd /c $($source -replace "'", "''''" )"
```

This may look strange, but it's just the same as
`JSON.stringify({a: "\\"}) === "{\"a\":\"\\\\\"}"` in JavaScript.

but it's much easier without using Invoke-Expression as already answered.

```bsh
& ".\a'b.bat"
& '.\a''b.bat'
```